# Abrir projeto com Localhost - Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

procurei durante todo o dia e já pedi ajuda a muita gente porém não encontro o que realmente procuro.

Eu preciso de um tutorial passo a passo de como abrir um projeto com o apache no Ubuntu.

O apache2 está instalado, o mysql está instalado e o PHP5 também está instalado.

eu já tentei criar uma pasta dentro do /var/www porém se eu digitar o localhost seguido do nome da pasta o navegador informa que o diretorio/arquivo não existe.

Comment: Já exprerimentou colocar apenas localhost para verificar se aparece a página padrão do Apache?

Comment: Sim Giancarlo, aparece sim o "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page It's Work!"

Comment: entra na pasta /var/www e executa o comando sudo chmod -Rf 777 nome da pasta. Outra coisa é remover o arquivo index.php ou index.html da pasta var/www. Assim voce consegue olhar o diretorio dentro do localhost. Olha isso:https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu_pt_BR.html

Comment: Tenho a solução do seu problema. Dá uma olhadinha na minha resposta ;)

Comment: em alguns ubuntu a pasta é /var/www/html, e você deve acessar http://localhost para acessar a pasta /var/www/html e não acessar esse diretório no navegador, entendi que voce tentou isso

Answer (score 2):

No ubuntu, o apache, com suas configurações padrões, não executa as pastas que estão dentro de `var/www`, e sim as que estão dentro de `var/www/html`.

Coloque os arquivos ou pastas dentro de `var/www/html`, e o problema será resolvido.

Existe também uma forma de configurar para que outras pastas também possam ser reconhecidas pelo `apache`.

Eu costumo fazer o seguinte.

- Crio um arquivo `.conf` dentro da pasta `sites-avaliable`. Nesse caso, vamos criar `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/minha_pasta.conf`.
- Confiro o arquivo `.conf`:

Exemplo - arquivo `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/minha_pasta.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.2
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/minha_pasta
</VirtualHost>
```

- Utilizo o comando `a2ensite` para habilitá-lo no apache.

Exemplo:

```
 a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/minha_pasta.conf
```

Depois, reiniciamos o apache, digitando na linha de comando `service apache2 restart`